# Data Binding is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

To enable data binding, I added to the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

In my fragment, I added:

```kotlin
private var _binding: WebViewFragmentBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = WebViewFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

This works so far until I change the layout from:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebViewFragment">

    // more layout elements

</FrameLayout>
```

to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="name"
            type="String" />

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".WebViewFragment">

        // more layout elements

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

When I add the `layout` element, the `_binding` object is `null`.

I have no idea what is wrong with my code. When I run the app, it crashes with an NPE, but there is no inflating error or anything on the console.

Comment: Are you accessing `binding` anywhere else apart from when returning from `onCreateView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
private var _binding: WebViewFragmentBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
_binding = WebViewFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
return _binding.root
}
```

use this _binding any where like _binding.youView

Comment: This is what I did, but `_binding` itself is `null` :-(